# TCP Connection window size

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

A 10 Mbps congested non-buffered link is used to send a huge file between two hosts. The receiving host has a large buffer than the congestion window. Assume the turnaround time is 100 ms, and the TCP Reno connection is always in congestion avoidance phase

what is the max window size (in segment) that this TCP connection can achieve?

Im using the formula W*MSS/RTT=10Mbps

I have RTT which is 100ms but im not sure where to get the MSS(maximum segment size) to be able to solve for W

Comment: W = 10*1000000*8 * 100/2/1000. I don't see where MSS comes into it, but it is typically around 1280.

Comment: 100/2/1000 where is this coming from?